# make a class alias to call static methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I correctly define an alias for a class and use that alias to call some static methods?

let's assume that i have this class

```
class theClassThatIWantToAlias{
    static theStaticMethod(){
        console.log("called")
    }
}

/* I can call the statc method doing so */
theClassThatIWantToAlias.theStaticMethod();
```

I want to create an alias for be able to call the method as

```
theClassThatIWantToAlias -> myAlias;
myAlias.theStaticMethod();
```

I thought to do this things

```js
/* 1) define a type from the class */
type alias = theClassThatIWantToAlias;
alias.theStaticMethod();

/* 2) define an interface from the class */
interface alias extends theClassThatIWantToAlias {}
alias.theStaticMethod();

/* 3) Define a new class that extend the main one */
class alias extends theClassThatIWantToAlias {} 
alias.theStaticMethod();
```

I'm pretty sure that the first two are *no-sense* and i'm wondering if the third one is a 'coorect' way for accomplish this task. Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neither want to declare a type or interface nor define a new class. All you want to do is introduce another variable that holds the same class object:

```
const Alias = TheClassThatIWantToAlias;
```

Comment: But then if you do `Alias.name` it'll still be `'TheClassThatIWantToAlias'`.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy Sure, while you can have many aliases referring to the same class, its `.name` property can only have one value. Why would that be a problem?